# Duvida com JSON no Autocomplete JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Tenho o seguinte JSON de retorno

```
{"cliente":[  
            {"id":"1","nome":"Fulano"},  
            {"id":"2","nome":"Ciclado"}  
]}
```

E preciso popular meu `autocomplete`,

```
$('#nome').autocomplete({  
      source: function(request, response){  
        $.ajax({  
            url:"http://192.168.254.103:12514/web-parbs/htdocs/json/clientes.jsp",  
            dataType:"json",  
            success: function(data){  
                response($.map(data, function(item){  
                    return {  
                        label: item.id,  
                        value: item.nome  
                    };  
                }))  
            }})  
      }  
    });
```

Essa foi uma das soluções que pesquisei, o problema é que o item retorna um Vetor, estou com problemas para percorrer de uma forma que fique 
label: o nome do cliente pra ser exibido no campo e o value: o id do cliente.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Porque não chama o `$.map` passando `data.cliente` em vez de `data`? Na verdade o resultado do `$.map` esta correto.

Comment: Cara, era só isso mesmo, pesquisei tanto e não vi esse erro.
Mesmo assim, obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `map` traduz um objeto (ou lista) em uma lista, onde você deve passar uma função que faça a transformação. Ele itera sobre as propriedades e invoca sua função para popular a nova lista.

O problema no seu caso, é que está passando um objeto com apenas uma propriedade própria ao invés de passar a lista de clientes.

Basta chamar a função `$.map` passando o `data.cliente` ao invés de `data` apenas.

Esse [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7572mmh7/) exemplifica a solução.

Comment: Obrigado!! É isso mesmo.